# Using a function in a full cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The problem:

I have a (big) column of numbers, most of which are 3-digit, some of them are 2-digit. I'd like to replace every two-digit number with first 3-digit number above.

My question:

Is there a way to do that? I was thinking of assigning a function to each cell in a column. This function would replace the value with a previous 3-digit if the value in cell was 2-digit, BUT do not change the value in the cell if it was 3-digit. But how do I insert a function into a full cell?

Comment: If you want to do it via formula, you need to use a helper column to return the desired result then overwrite the original column. If you want to overwrite the values in the original column directly you may need some help from `#vba`. Please post some mocked up data say 15 rows of your random 2-digit and 3-digit list, and demonstrate the expected result in another column.

Answer (score 1):

Assume data housed in column A with header in `A1`

and, `A2` must started with 3-digit number

Then,

Formula in `B2`, copied down :

```
=IF(LEN(A2)=3,A2,B1)
```

Comment: Well, the number above the current in the result cell has to be a 3 digit number and represents the last 3 digit number from the first column. So this solution is much easier then mine.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be: **ARRAY-FORMULA: CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER**

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=3,A1,INDEX($A$1:A1,MAX(IF(LEN($A$1:A1)=3,ROW($A$1:A1)))))
```

[image]